# Replace certain words in multiple strings PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I have a database of strings and a database of words and their corrections. I need to find the words within the strings and replace them with their corrections. I cannot figure out how to do it and have it loop through all of the strings in the database. I need help.

I was thinking along the lines of the following pseudo code"

```
//while loop to grab all the strings from db

//add all the words to look for to an array
//add all of the word replacements to an array

//preg replace or str replace the words with the replacements in the string.
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Example input and output would be handy!

Comment: Are you trying to replace the strings in the database? Or is this for output only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would take a look at using [`strtr`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtr.php). This takes a string (sentence) as the first parameter and an array of key/value pairs as replacement text.

```
<?php

$sentence = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog";
$replacements = array("quick" => "fast", "brown" => "white", "fox" => "hair");

echo strtr($sentence, $replacements);
```

Yields:

```
The fast white hair jumps over the lazy dog
```

I would also read up on [`Tokenization`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tokenization) if you are not familiar with it as a concept. It may help you understand the underlying logic behind how this works.

Comment: Was able to load the data into the array from mysql and make the replacements. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you put all of the strings into an array `$orig`, all of the words into an array `$words`, and all of the corrections in to an array `$corrections`, you can just do this:

```
$corrected = str_replace($words, $corrections, $orig);
```

[Here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) is the documentation on `str_replace`.